# Text alignment in a Marginpar (Arabic)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, marginpar, arabic

how can I write a marginpar in Arabic with a text alignment from right to left.

I use XeLaTeX.

When I write

```
\marginpar{{\A كتاب حلية الأبدال وما يظهر عنها من المعارف والأحوال}}
```

Then that comes as a result

The A definition is for:

```
\newfontfamily{\A}{Geeza Pro}
```

The last word shall be right justified.

Thank you for helping me.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside=true,a5paper,pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage[ german]{babel}
\usepackage [para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{marginnote} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\newcommand{\mymparsetup}{\itshape}
\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\Roman{endnote}} 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\arabic{footnote}}}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Bemerkungen und Kommentare}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}  {\normalfont\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\newfontfamily{\A}{Geeza Pro}
\newfontfamily{\B}{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily{\C}{AGA Arabesque}

\title{Die spirituelle Metamorphose}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Einführendes Kapitel}


\marginpar{{\A كتاب حلية الأبدال وما يظهر عنها من المعارف والأحوال}} 
Dank gebührt Allah {\C} für das, wozu er uns inspiriert 
hat sowie für seine Belehrung dessen, was wir nicht wussten. 
Wahrlich die Gunst Allahs gegenüber uns ist gewaltig. 
Und Friede und Segen seien auf dem größten Meister, 
dem edelsten Propheten, welchem... 

 ...


 \newpage

 \theendnotes
 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Bidirectional typesetting is provided by the `bidi` package.  Given that you are using XeLaTeX, then you can load the `polyglossia` package instead of `babel`, and this will use the `bidi` package as necessary.   He is an example, based on the core of your code:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside=true,a5paper,pagesize]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}{Geeza Pro}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Einführendes Kapitel}

\marginpar{\begin{Arabic}
كتاب حلية الأبدال وما يظهر عنها من المعارف والأحوال
\end{Arabic}} 
Dank gebührt Allah für das, wozu er uns inspiriert 
hat sowie für seine Belehrung dessen, was wir nicht wussten. 
Wahrlich die Gunst Allahs gegenüber uns ist gewaltig. 
Und Friede und Segen seien auf dem größten Meister, 
dem edelsten Propheten, welchem\dots

\end{document}
```

Note that as you are using `titlesec` it needs to be loaded before `polyglossia`.  Also you need to set a font explicit font for arabic text via `\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}{...}`.